# ConvertAll ExtensionMethod in List<T> how to?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I want to write my extension method for `ConvertAll` method in `List<T>`.I have written like this below.

```
public static List<TOutput> MyConvertAll<TOutput>(this List<T> list, Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
{
}
```

But It gives me error:

> *Error: The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Please help me how to write?

Comment: All answers are correct but, besides that.. Why MyConvertAll? What's wrong with Select?

Comment: Yeah.. the `Converter` parameter is exactly like the transformation expression that Select takes.

Answer (score 3):

You must declare type parameter T.

```
public static List<TOutput> MyConvertAll<TOutput, T>(this List<T> list, Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare all your generic type parameters in your method definition, like this:

```
public static List<TOutput> MyConvertAll<T, TOutput>(this List<T> list, Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method needs to be generic in two parameters:

```
public static List<TOutput> MyConvertAll<T,TOutput>(this List<T> list, Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
```